# Find all the subsequential limits of each of the following sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find all the subsequential limits of each of the following sequences. Below is what I am thinking, but am I correct?

**c)$\lbrace (-1)^n + 2sin \frac{n \pi}{2}\rbrace$**

$a_n = (-1)^n + 2sin \frac{n \pi}{2}$

$a_1= (-1)^1 + 2sin \frac{\pi}{2} = 1$

$a_2= (-1)^2 + 2sin \frac{2 \pi}{2} = 1$

$a_3= (-1)^3 + 2sin \frac{3 \pi}{2} = -3$

$a_4= (-1)^4 + 2sin \frac{4 \pi}{2} = 1$

$a_5= (-1)^5 + 2sin \frac{5 \pi}{2} = 1$

$a_6= (-1)^6 + 2sin \frac{6 \pi}{2} = 1$

$a_7= (-1)^7 + 2sin \frac{7 \pi}{2} = -3$

$a_8= (-1)^8 + 2sin \frac{8 \pi}{2} = 1$

$a_9= (-1)^9 + 2sin \frac{9 \pi}{2} = 1$

$*$ This sequence is not convergent, so...

The subsequence $\lbrace a_{4n-3} \rbrace = \lbrace 1,1,1... \rbrace$, hence it converges to 1.

The subsequence $\lbrace a_{4n-2} \rbrace = \lbrace 1,1,1... \rbrace$, hence it converges to 1.

The subsequence $\lbrace a_{4n-1} \rbrace = \lbrace -3,-3,-3... \rbrace$, hence it converges to -3.

The subsequence $\lbrace a_{4n} \rbrace = \lbrace 1,1,1... \rbrace$, hence it converges to 1.

Therefore, the subsequential limits are $\lbrace -3, 1 \rbrace$

**d) $\lbrace n sin \frac{n \pi}{4}\rbrace$**

$a_n = n sin \frac{n \pi}{4}$

$a_1 = 1 sin \frac{\pi}{4} = .707$

$a_2 = 2 sin \frac{2 \pi}{4} = 2$

$a_3 = 3 sin \frac{3 \pi}{4} = 2.121$

$a_4 = 4 sin \frac{4 \pi}{4} = 0$

$a_5 = 5 sin \frac{5 \pi}{4} = -3.53$

$a_6 = 6 sin \frac{6 \pi}{4} = -6$

$a_7 = 7 sin \frac{7 \pi}{4} = -4.949$

$a_8 = 8 sin \frac{8 \pi}{4} = 0$

$a_9 = 9 sin \frac{9 \pi}{4} = 6.3639$

$*$ This sequence is not convergent, so...

The subsequence $\lbrace a_{4n} \rbrace = \lbrace 0,0,0... \rbrace$, hence it converges to 0.

Therefore, the subsequential limits are $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$

f)$\lbrace (1.5 + (-1)^n)^n\rbrace$

$a_n = (1.5 + (-1)^n)^n$

$a_1 = (1.5 + (-1)^1)^1= .5$

$a_2 = (1.5 + (-1)^2)^2= 6.25$

$a_3 = (1.5 + (-1)^3)^3= .125$

$a_4 = (1.5 + (-1)^4)^4= 39.0625$

$a_5 = (1.5 + (-1)^5)^5= .0312$

$a_6 = (1.5 + (-1)^6)^6= 244.14$

$*$ This sequence is not convergent, so...

The subsequence $\lbrace a_{2n} \rbrace = \lbrace 6.25, 39.0625, 244.14... \rbrace$, hence it does not converge.

The subsequence $\lbrace a_{2n+1} \rbrace = \lbrace .5, .125, .03125... \rbrace$, hence it converges to 0.

Therefore, the subsequential limit is $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$

Comment: All the answers seem fine to me.

Comment: Yeah, and they lack proofs.